# Read multiple lines from xml column to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm struggling reading data from measurements stored as xml columns. My xml files looks like this:

```
<Data t0="2018-09-18T07:43:11.882+01:00" dt="2.003338853E-5">
  <Measurement>
    <Value>2.075</Value>
    <Value>2.175</Value>
    <Value>2.275</Value>
    <Value>2.325</Value>
    <Value>2.425</Value>
    ...
  </Measurement>
</Data>
```

What I need as result is a table containing the values.

What I already tried is this:

```
SELECT      CONVERT(varchar(max),c.query('data(Value)')) as XMLValues
FROM        [dbo].[T_Measurement] as t1
                CROSS APPLY Measurement.nodes('/Data/Measurement') x(c)
```

which creates a resulting xml field with space separated values. But how can I create a query resulting in a table?

regards, Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `query()` to extract the values and then `value` to cast them to a numeric type:

```sql
declare @tmp table (Measurement xml)

insert into @tmp 
select 
'<Data t0="2018-09-18T07:43:11.882+01:00" dt="2.003338853E-5"> 
  <Measurement>          
    <Value>2.075</Value> 
    <Value>2.175</Value> 
    <Value>2.275</Value> 
    <Value>2.325</Value> 
    <Value>2.425</Value> 
  </Measurement> 
</Data>'

SELECT  
    Tbl.Col.value('.','decimal(18,3)') as XMLValues
FROM @tmp as t1
    CROSS APPLY Measurement.nodes('/Data/Measurement/Value') Tbl(Col)
```

Result:

[image]

If you have multiple measurements in a single file (for example with an attribute that identifies each Measurement):

```sql
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (Measurement XML)

INSERT INTO @tmp
SELECT '<Data t0="2018-09-18T07:43:11.882+01:00" dt="2.003338853E-5"> 
  <Measurement setId="1">          
    <Value>1.075</Value> 
    <Value>1.175</Value> 
    <Value>1.275</Value> 
    <Value>1.325</Value> 
    <Value>1.425</Value> 
  </Measurement> 
  <Measurement setId="2">          
    <Value>2.076</Value> 
    <Value>2.176</Value> 
    <Value>2.276</Value> 
    <Value>2.326</Value> 
    <Value>2.426</Value> 
  </Measurement> 
</Data>'

SELECT 
    Tbl.Col.value('../@setId', 'int')   as setId,
    Tbl.Col.value('.', 'decimal(18,3)') as XMLValues 
FROM @tmp AS t1
CROSS APPLY Measurement.nodes('/Data/Measurement/Value') Tbl(Col)
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: additionally: how would the query look like for more than one set of measurements? e.g. Data doesn't only contain the dataset 'Measurement' but also a dataset called 'Measurement2'?

Comment: @Daniel Please see updated answer. You can go up one level with `../` and read the attributes of the parent tag to identify each measurement